# Smarty optimization for sending emails

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, smarty

I am using symfony 1.4, smarty and LAMP
I want to know what could be the best way of optimization in my case.

My email template is divided into three parts:

1. Header (static)
2. Body   (can be either static or variable)
3. Footer (non -static as its got an unsubscribe link and i know to pass a unique id)

code of mail template

```
~$commonheader
~$body
~footer
```

I am using partials for header footer and body, which means for ever mailer all these will be parsed.

What should i do that static part should not be parsed again and again

Comment: If you use Symfony, have you considered Twig for your templates ?

Comment: i cant use Twig, i cant change the code base now

Answer (score 2):

You should enable smarty caching (See http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/caching) and use insert instead of include. As smarty documentation says:

> It is possible to have portions of the template not cached. If you have caching turned on, {insert} tags will not be cached. They will run dynamically every time the page is created, even within cached pages. This works good for things like banners, polls, live weather, search results, user feedback areas, etc.

So, an example code would be:

**test.php**

```
<?
require_once("lib/smarty/Smarty.class.php");
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->setTemplateDir( 'templates' );
$smarty->setCompileDir( 'templates_c' );
$smarty->setCacheDir( 'templates_cache' );
$smarty->setConfigDir( 'templates_config' );
$smarty->caching = 1;
$smarty->compile_check = true;

function insert_Body() 
{
    global $smarty;
    ob_start();
    $smarty->display("search.tpl");
    $ret =  ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $ret;
}

$smarty->display("test.tpl");
```

**test.tpl**

```
<h1>Smarty test</h1>
{insert name="body"}
<hr>
```

Insert tag will look a php file for a function named "insert_" followed by the name passed. In this example it is insert_Body();

You can also pass variables to the function, for instance, file name to include. From Smarty documentation (http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.insert.tpl)

```
{insert name="getBanner" lid=#banner_location_id# sid=#site_id#}
```

> Smarty would call this function: insert_getBanner(array("lid" =>
>   "12345","sid" => "67890")); and display the returned results in place
>   of the {insert} tag.

Note that the value should be returned by the function but no echoed. That is why I used ob_start() & ob_end_clean() with ob_get_contents()